# How did the React.createClass‘s Arguments spec added a displayName prop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My code:

```
var Counter = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
      return { clickCount: 0 };
    },
    handleClick: function () {
      this.setState({clickCount: this.state.clickCount + 1});
    },
    render: function () {
      return (<h2 onClick={this.handleClick}>Click me! Number of clicks: {this.state.clickCount}</h2>);
    }
  });
```

In ReactClass:

```
  createClass: function (spec) {
   debugger
   var Constructor = function (props, context, updater) {
   // This constructor gets overridden by mocks. The argument is used
   // by mocks to assert on what gets mounted.
   ....
```

When I debug the createClass the spec.displayName is 'Counter'.
How did it come to be? 
It's messing with me!

Comment: Hi Tim, it's hard for me to understand your question. Maybe adding a few more sentences about which parts of the code are causing the problem and what the expected outcome is would help.

Comment: @Himmel He's asking how `createClass` can know about the name `Counter` which is the name of the return value.

Comment: @Himmel, azium is right, `spec.displayName` is `'Counter'`, but I do never define the `displayName` property in my put in parameter object.

Comment: `var Counter = function () {}; console.log(Counter.name)`